# Inside menu opens 2px top in Firefox

Tags: css, menu

The problem is menu openning in the wrong place only in firefox. I thought about putting top:2px position:relative but it`ll effect all browsers

http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/6884/unled1copyqj.jpg

my website; http://tinyurl.com/3g58vhb

Comment: What about adding margin-top with a firefox css hack? yourlement, x:-moz-any-link { margin-top: 2px }

Comment: it's better if he can fixed it anywhere ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the position: absolute but do not define a top value. Try using top: x inside your CSS and it should be on the same position on every browser.

If your header can move up and down. Give the parent node of the submenu (LI) the css property position: relative, but still define the top property.

Comment: I just added -> top:28px; and it is looking perfect ! Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

adjust the padding like this :

```
 height: 17px;
 padding: 6px 10px;
```

And add height to your `nav li a {` class, should work